# Entity Framework "Code First" not seeding or creating databases - no errors

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

For some reason my DB is not being created and i'm not getting any errors. I'm using "SQL Server"

Tring to initialize the DB in the global.asax.ca file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //BREAKPOINT HITS. GOOD
     Database.SetInitializer<MenuManagerContext>(new MenuManagerServiceInitializer()); 
}
```

...

```
public class MenuManagerServiceInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MenuManagerContext>
{
    //BREAKPOINT NEVER HITS. BAD
    protected override void Seed(MenuManagerContext context)
    {
        context.Chains.Add(...);

        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the database is not being created? I'm not even getting errors so it's very hard to tell what is wrong...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Database.SetInitializer` doesn't cause the database to be created. It's only setting the initialization strategy.

The DB is created if you are using a context for the very first time, for instance by issuing any query, or by attaching or adding an object to the context, and so on.

Comment: I have similer case as above. Before it works fine. lat time I added about 15 entities. After that db creation stops. No errors pops up. no db created. But ONModelCreating is get called in context. 

How do I know the reason to happen this ?

Comment: @DineshN.Samarathunga: I don't know. I'd recommend to ask and describe the problem in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Make a call to an Action that returns data through your context

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //should trigger call to MenuManagerServiceInitializer.Seed()
    return View(new MenuManagerContext().Chains.ToList())
}
```